# Avoid Translucent Activity from listening to onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

I have a Translucent Activity with the theme `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.Translucent`

As this `Activity` is completely transparent, the user does not know that the `Activity` exists. Therefore when the user presses the back button, the default behaviour should be that whichever `Activity` the user was last on, should take the back button event.

But here as the Translucent Activity is on top, it takes the event and it appears to the user that the back button did not work on the first try. Is there any way where I can either send a back key event some milliseconds after `onBackPressed()`, or where I can set my `Activity` to not listen to key events at all? There are some flags like `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` which tell that the app does not want to be touched, but this does not work on the back button for me.

Please do not suggest me to use a `Service` because it is absolutely necessary for me to use an `Activity` and it should be transparent too.

Comment: If you dont override on back pressed then the default implementation is to call super.onBackPressed method! If you override and do nothing then the user wont leave your activity using back key event. So the issue milliseconds clarify for me since its the easiest to do! and also why do you want a transparent activity? there are alternatives like dialog activities?

Comment: I forgot to include in question that the activity is called by a service. An Accessibility service, to be exact. Whenever the user launches a third party app, the Accessibility service triggers and loads my Translucent activity. So I want the back presses to be listened by the third party app which is behind my app. Either this, or my app should take the event and then press back button on the previous app itself so user does not feel it.

Comment: As to why I must use an Activity: I need to take screenshot of third party apps using mediaprojection API, which requires me to call startActivityForResult() and then wait for a result.

Comment: I am doubting if what you need is possible? it looks hacky and security prone!

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Translucent activity with `startActivityForResult()` and then override the `onBackPressed` function in the Translucent activity. So you can proceed doing something like this.

In your MainActivity or calling activity, start the translucent activity like this.

```
private static final int TRANSLUCENT_ACTIVITY = 101;

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourTranslucentActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, TRANSLUCENT_ACTIVITY);
```

And override the `onActivityResult` like this.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == RETURNED_FROM_TRANSLUCENT_ACTIVITY) {
        // Call the backPressed function in your calling Activity
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Now in the translucent activity, you need to override the `onBackPressed` like this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

So the trick is not avoiding the back pressed function but making another way to behave exactly what you're expecting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I forgot to include in question that the activity is called by a service. An Accessibility service, to be exact. Whenever the user launches a third party app, the Accessibility service triggers and loads my Translucent activity. So I want the back presses to be listened by the third party app which is behind my app. Either this, or my app should take the event and then press back button on the previous app itself so user does not feel it.